# Build a Vue component for "unpkg"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, build, components

I want to publish my component on unpkg.com. Actually [it is there](https://unpkg.com/vue-polar@0.2.1/dist/vuePolar.umd.min.js), but not working. I tried to use the same build (umd) as for my npm build, but I think I would need a specific build for unpkg. Here are the relevant parts of my `package.json` now:

```
  ...
  "main": "dist/vuePolar.umd.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/vuePolar.umd.min.js",
  "scripts": {
    "package": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name vuePolar src/components/Polar.vue",
    ...
  }
```

I suspect I need to build a IIFE instead of an UMD file, but there is nothing like that in my dist folder:

```
demo.html
vuePolar.common.js
vuePolar.common.js.map
vuePolar.umd.js
vuePolar.umd.js.map
vuePolar.umd.min.js
vuePolar.umd.min.js.map
```

Any idea how to get a build that works with unkpg?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is ok to publish your component as UMD. I had to register my component in the Vue instance, like so:

```html
<div id="app">
    <polar :item="3">hoi</polar>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: { polar: vuePolar},
    })
</script>
```

Now it works. I got confused by an example that did not require the component to be registered.